# Yii2 rest api basic auth

Tags: rest, yii2, basic-authentication, yii2-advanced-app

I need Basic authentication in Yii2 rest API:

Api controller:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator']['class'] = HttpBasicAuth::className();
        $behaviors['authenticator']['auth'] = function ($username, $password) {
            return \app\models\User::findOne([
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
            ]);
        };
    }
```

My Requwest:

> login:password@api/users

How fix it?

Error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
 if ($this->_behaviors === null) {
            $this->_behaviors = [];
            foreach ($this->behaviors() as $name => $behavior) {
                $this->attachBehaviorInternal($name, $behavior);
            }
        }
```

Line with "foreach".

Comment: Fix what? you didn't tell what problem you have and you need to verify the password if it is matching, you won't be sending a decoded password in the request the sent password would be a normal text which needs to be converted using the same algo with which it is being saved in the database, and then you should compare both of them

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
   public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
```

Url for Get: username:password@api/users